# Sci-fi novel with Aristocrats who own Soldiers, and a lead character named 3R1CK

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm looking for a sci-fi book I read in 2013–2016. I think it was published in the 70s.

It's about this one dude who was born as a Soldier, but gets bought by a beautiful young Aristocrat. (Aristocrats and Soldiers are races in this book. Aristocrats are the wealthy who buy and sell Soldiers, who are bred, raised, and trained as human pawns in petty wars.)

Anyways, the Soldier, whose name is 3rd Regiment 1st Command Soldier K, 3R1CK for short, or Erick, ends up falling in love with his Aristocrat, whose name I think is Pauline. She decides to free him from servitude, by marrying him. That matters, because this is an offense punishable by a "fate worse than death," though I don't think the book clarifies what this fate is.

They have to run away to the verge of the world, where they find out that the world they live in is a "bubble world," that's watched over by a council of Lords, and these bubble worlds are kind of used as entertainment for these Lords, who decide everything for the citizens, from weather to diet.

That's about halfway through the book, but it's all I remember, since I never finished it. Anything helps.

I am very confident about the name 3R1CK, for the specific reason that I remember explaining the naming system of the army to a friend of mine. The Soldiers are more or less given a serial code and a year based on their placement in the "army". Every year has 5 Regiments; every Regiment has 5 commands; every command has 26 Soldiers, each given their own letter. Our lead is Soldier K, so his serial name is 3R1CK. The other names I'm not so sure of.

Comment: You would think _3R1CK_ was so distinctive a name it would be simple to Google, but I've had no luck searching for it.

Comment: @Adam - When were you in middle school?

Comment: @LogicDictates I was in middle school from 2013-2016

Comment: How confident are you of the names? Specifics like "aristocrats", "3R1ck", for example? The acronym "3rd Regiment 1st Command Soldier" actually spells 3R1CS

Comment: @Valorum, I am very confident about the name 3R1CK, for the specific reason of I remember explaining the naming system of the army to a friend of mine. The Soldiers are more or less given a serial code and a year based off their placement in the "army". Every year has 5 Regiments, every Regiment had 5 commands, every command has 26 Soldiers, each given their own letter. Our lead is Soldier K, so his serial name is 3R1CK. The other names I'm not so sure of.

Comment: @Adam - Nothing found on Google Books; https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%223R1CK%22

Comment: You could improve this Story-Identification question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/tips-for-asking-story-identification-questions) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.